# What is the easiest way to do deep copy of a struct in C?

Tags: c, struct, deep-copy

Suppose I have a

```
struct A{
char *name;
unsigned long *trunks;
bool value;
const struct smap *smap;
...
...
}
```

This struct has all types of data structures and I do not have direct exposure to the struct apart from struct A A*, which is a pointer to it.

Comment: There is no easy way. You have to write it yourself.

Comment: `struct A A*` makes no sense. Explain clearer, what you have and what you don't. In any case, it is not possible to make a deep copy without having a deep knowledge of how the data is organized. What is `trunks`? A pointer to a lone `unsigned long` or a pointer to an array of `unsigned long`? If the latter is true, then how long is the array? Are all member pointers supposed to be deep-copied or only some of them?

Comment: Yes, all the members are to be deeply copied. I meant struct A *A. *trunks is a pointer to bitmap array. The struct has lot more fields, but I am trying to find a generic solution to all of them. Lot of fields are being defined somewhere else, where I do not have all the access.

Comment: I agree with the others that there is no easy way as such. However, if this is something you need often enough and is important enough one approach is to write an ELF parser that extracts the relevant struct info and auto generates code to do the copy. There may even be code out there to do that already if you are lucky. There certainly are lots of ELF parsers (e.g. [pyelftools](https://github.com/eliben/pyelftools)) so in the worst case you can take one of those and add in your struct copy code generation.

Comment: Got it. Can you tell me how do I duplicate struct pointers and others pointers?

Comment: @RohanShah: asking that question is a clear signal you should really get more comfortable with pointers and objects in C. You don't need to dub a pointer, but the object it references (see my answer).

Comment: @AlanAu: Thanks for the info about ELF parsers. That might come in handy for some project I have in mind. And Python would have been my preferred PL for this.

Comment: C does not have the kind of type introspection required to do this for arbitrary depth. If you want to do this, you will need to build introspection into your types.

Comment: @Olaf No worries. I should clarify that parsing ELF itself is not enough as it does not inherently give you the C components (struct elements in this case). One needs to generate and parse the DWARF info in the ELF file. Fortunately many ELF parsers, including pyelftools, do handle DWARF.

Comment: @AlanAu: I am very well aware of this. And that is not what I need. I was just afraid I would have to write one on my own (already did this years ago for ELF's predecessor COFF in C), so I am glad, there is something to start with and even in my favorite language:-) At least I can use that as a starter. However, the idea to use the object file itself to create copy code is quite an appealing idea. I've used already some Python code to create code (great if using Scons), but not thought about the object files themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy every element in the struct and all referenced objects to newly allocated structures the same way (recursively).

If the struct has only few pointers, you might use memcpy to copy all elements as-is first and then copy all referenced (through pointers) objects in a second pass. If there are many pointers, it might be more efficient to copy each field by hand.

Referenced objects must be treated identical (by recursion, iteration would be pretty nasty). However, for this, you need to know the structure of these types. Alternatively, there might be copy functions for all these objects in their implemenation file, thus keeping them opaque. If neither the structure, nor a copy function is available, you are somewhat lost, as there is no way to detect the pointers without that.

A problem will arise if there are circular references. Then things get even more complicated.

Comment: Small nitpick: No need for `memcpy` on first step; you can do the shallow copy with simple assignment and keep type safety.

Comment: @user694733: Thanks, I just forgot about that (wonder why). Yes, you're right and that leaves the actual method to the compiler.